# Move Object by dragging (mobile) makes the balls fall from the cup

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have this cup that contains balls inside. All 2D
I am using Rigidbody2d and Collider2d.

When running in unity and moving the cup (with arrow keys) the balls stay inside the cup. I also added drag movement for Android touch to move the cup.

The problem is that when moving the cup too fast (by draging) the balls fall from the cup collider (using Polygon colider 2d).

Code for movement is:

```
 public float speed = 0.1F;
    void Update() {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
            transform.Translate(-touchDeltaPosition.x * speed, -touchDeltaPosition.y * speed, 0);
        }
    }
```

I tried to play with the speed parameter but it wont really help. if the cup movement is too slow it is not very useful for me.
I believe it is related the velocity/force of the ball or cup which makes the cup collider miss...

Any help on this would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you are moving it by changing the position of the cup, that means that when you move it fast, it disappears, and reappears where you dragged it, leaving the balls behind, and then they fall. I had the same thing where my objects would just go through the walls and out of the camera area. I fixed that by using AddForce. This makes the cup move, position by position over to where you dragged. this bumps the balls along, and they stay in the cup. This is what I guess is going on. If you use velocity that would work to.

you could rather than transform.Translate, you could find the vector to where you want to move to.

```
var direction = touchDeltaPosition - transform.position;
gameObject.rigidbody2D.velocity.x = direction.x * speed;
gameObject.rigidbody2D.velocity.y = direction.y * speed;
```

hope this solves it

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. So i should use AddForce or Velocity?

Comment: you can use either, each has its advantages. I lik velocity, because I am used to thinking about it that way. But AddForce is just as good, probably simpler.

Comment: gameObject.rigidbody2D.AddForce(direction);

Comment: I see, by the way transform.position is Vector3d while touchDeltaPosition (Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;) is using Vecctor2d. So i can't cast it..:\

Comment: you can transform the Vector3 to a Vector2 by going   var newVec = new Vector2 (direction.x, direction.y);

Comment: Managed to make it work, thanks.. added the code below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, when you're moving the cup too fast, at Frame 1 the ball is inside the cup, but at Frame 2 it's outside. You can reduce the value of "Fixed Timestep" (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html) to increase the frequency of the physics calculations, or make the colliders larger.

If a ball in the cup will always stay in the cup, maybe you can turn off the physics of the ball once it's in the cup, or something along those lines.

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply. I tried changing the polygon to 3 wider box colliders and still balls fall . I tried to reduce the Fixed TimeStep , maybe it did help a little but balls still fall.. This is getting frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

Usually transform.Translate() is not very efficient when dealing with colliders, instead, you can try three other solutions:
1) rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2.Up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
2) rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(//write what you need);
3) which I consider the best solution for dealing with colliders and dragging is : MoveRigidbody2D

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what worked for me:

```
        var newVec = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        var touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition*touchSpeed;
        var direction = touchDeltaPosition- newVec;
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(direction);
```